read details based on collection of multiple columns in sql
I have a requirement to read data from the db tables.
There are two tables one has the sports league table that contains the details of the leagues, the other table contains all the players in each league. A player can participate in any number of leagues.
The sample data is shown below.
LEAGUE_TEAM                         
_______________                 
ID      NAME    
____  ________
1       EPL
2       IPL
3       CPL
4       BPL
5       BBL


        PLAYER_DETAILS
    _______________________         
LEAGUE_ID       PLAYER_LAST_NAME   PLAYER_FIRST_NAME
___________  ___________________   _________________

1               Silva               Thiago
2               Silva               Thiago
3               Silva               Thiago
1               Lampard             Frank
2               Lampard             Frank
1               Caballero           Willy
2               Caballero           Willy
3               Caballero           Willy
4               Caballero           Willy
5               Caballero           Willy
4               Mount               Mason

The input data is a collection of player names in the json format with last_name and first_name. Using this supplied list of player names, I should identify to which league these players belongs to.
Eg: If the input details are
1.
last_name       first_name
__________      ___________
silva           Thiago
Caballero       Willy

The sql query should result league 1,2 and 3 details, because these players are combinedly participating in EPL,IPL and CPL leagues.
2.
last_name       first_name
__________      ___________
Lampard         Frank
Caballero       Willy

The sql query should result league 1 and 2 details, because these two players are combinedly participating in EPL and IPL league.
3.
last_name       first_name
__________      ___________
Mount           Mason
Caballero       Willy

The sql query should result league 4 details, because these two players are combinedly participating in BPL league.
4.
last_name       first_name
__________      ___________
silva           Thiago
Lampard         Frank
Caballero       Willy

The sql query should result league 1 and 2 details, because these players are combinedly participating in EPL and IPL leagues.
So far all I got is simple sql query,
SELECT lt.* FROM LEAGUE_TEAM lt
    INNER JOIN PLAYER_DETAILS pd ON pd.league_id = lt.id
    WHERE pd.last_name = :last_name and pd.first_name = :first_name

Using this query,

I will be first reading the league details of one player from the given collection.
Then reading all the players from this resulted league from step 1.
Iterating all the players from step 2 and comparing with the remaining players in the input list.

This is very tedious process and I am not impressed. Just wanted to take help from the community if there is any SQL query that I can use to get the expected result.
Thanks in advance for all your support and help.
Environment:
Postgresql 16
Java 11 for programming


Your first paragraph is confusing. I am no sports-person, but… Don't you have a three levels of hierarchy, not two: players belong to a team, a team belongs to a league? You seem to be conflating team with league. Show your CREATE TABLE commands.

@BasilBourque, Don't take this data as is from the real sports events. I am working on a project for a client and the data in the requirement is domain specific. I came up with this sample data that is very close to the data in the project. So, do not try to map this data to a real league, team or player data. Also, ddl script is not relevant for my need. I need help where I have to use a collection of input data to figure out to which group this collection belongs to. Any suggestions are welcome

Q1 and the required answer don't match: Silva and Caballero play both in league 1, 2 and 3, not just 1.

"do not try to map this data to a real league" — Wouldn't it make sense for you to contrive an logical easy-to-understand scenario for us to work with?

Something like this, the condition in the HAVING:
SELECT id
     , name
     , array_agg(DISTINCT player_last_name ORDER BY player_last_name) -- to validate the output
FROM league_team
    JOIN player_details ON league_team.id = player_details.league_id
WHERE (player_last_name = 'Silva' AND player_first_name = 'Thiago')
OR    (player_last_name = 'Caballero' AND player_first_name = 'Willy')
GROUP BY id, name
HAVING count(*) = 2; -- 2 players


Thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a try. However, I would like to make clear that the input can have any number of players, not just two players. The examples I provided are only for understanding purpose. The requirement is to find out the league details based on the list of players supplied. The supplied data may have any number of players. I hope this gives you better understanding. However, I truly appreciate your time and help.

Just add more player in the WHERE condition and change the number, if you want to.

Your suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks again for your time and effort.
